# Bound on matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, upper-lower-bounds

I have a result of the form:

$r = A^\top B^\top B A$

Where $A_{[m \times 1]}$ and $B_{[n \times m]}$, so $A^\top A$ is a scalar.

I want to bound $r$ from below using some property of B, and reach the form:

$r \geq b \cdot (A^\top A)$, where $b$ is a scalar derived from the matrix $B$.

A simple example could be the case where $B$ is diagonal.
Then if $b = \min_i B_{i,i}^2$ (the minimal squared value found in $B$),  then the form above hold.

Is there anything I can use for the case $B$ is non diagonal? something that perhaps includes the $trace$ of $B$?

Comment: Does such an inequality even make sense? $r$ and $A^TA$ need not be scalars.

Comment: I apologise for not being clear. in my setting $A^\top A$ is a scalar.

Comment: It is more suggestive to denote $A$ as $x$, a vector that it is, and notice that $r=\|Bx\|^2$, with the dot product norm (assuming everything is real). So what you want is $\|Bx\|^2\geq b\,\|x\|^2$. The best estimate is to take $b$ to be the smallest singular value of $B$, i.e. the smallest eigenvalue of $B^\top B$, see [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) and [Singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information, the best you can say is $M = B^TB$ is a positive **semi**-definite $n\times n$ matrix;
this means $M$ may have an eigenvalue $0$.
In this case, if $A\neq 0$ is its associated eigenvector, we'd have $r = 0$, which would make $b=0$.

Notice that, as a linear transformation, $B: \Bbb R^m\longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$.
This means that when $m>n$ it's guaranteed that $B$ fails to be injective, and hence that $M$ has nontrivial kernel, that is, $M$ has an eigenvalue $0$.
In other words, you could only *hope* for $b>0$ when $m\leqslant n$.

In general, $b$ would be $M$'s smallest eigenvalue (all of which are real and non-negative).